# Importing React elements in to project

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to ReactJS but I've got off the ground and I've set up my first React project and all is going great, really enjoying using React.

I've been using 'JS Complete' to create and test my code - https://jscomplete.com/repl

In this I've created a simple table that pulls in some JSON data and displays it how I need which works great in the online tool - here's my code:

```
var shows = [
{
  id: 1,
  show: 'Simpsons',
  characters: [
  { id: 1, name: 'Bart Simpson', gender: 'Male'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Homer Simpson', gender: 'Male'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Ned Flanders', gender: 'Male'}
]
},
{
  id: 2,
  show: 'Flintstones',
  characters: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Fred Flintstone', gender: 'Male'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Barney Rubble', gender: 'Male'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Wilma Flintstone', gender: 'Female'}
]
}
];

const ShowTable = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>
      <h3>{props.show}</h3>
      <table>
        {props.characters.map((char, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{char.name}</td>
          <td>{char.gender}</td>
        </tr>
            ))}  
      </table>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};

const ShowList = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>
      {props.cards.map(card => <ShowTable {...card} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ShowList cards={shows} />, mountNode);
```

So what I now need to do is import this in to my project and this is where I'm falling over.

I've created a 'page' React element that pulls in my table React element - I did some tests pulling in a static React element that just said 'Hello World' which worked fine, so next I tried inserting the code above in to the React element changing the last line to this;

```
export default (ShowList cards={shows});
```

Which ... in my head should work but I have a feeling this is where I'm going wrong, testing in browser I'm getting a syntax error on that final line so I'm guessing I've done something wrong but again this looks fine to me, if someone can point out what I've done wrong I'd be very grateful!

Also I feel that the title to my question isn't very helpful for anyone who might bump in to this issue in the future - better suggestions welcomed! :-)

N

Answer (score 1):

The component is `ShowList`, so you would `export default ShowList`.

Then import it using `import ShowList from "ShowList.js"`.

And implement it using `<ShowList cards={shows}/>` where `shows` is defined in the component where the `ShowList` is imported.

**ShowList.js**

```
class ShowList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {props.cards.map(card => <ShowTable {...card} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ShowList;
```

**ShowListParent.js**

```
import ShowList from "ShowList.js";

class ShowListParent extends Component {
  render() {
    const shows = ['show1', 'show2'];

    return <ShowList cards={shows} />
  }
}

export default ShowListParent;
```

Comment: Yes I see what I'm doing wrong now! Let me see if I can get this working - thank you!

Comment: Any luck with the solution?